# ¿ porque cuango agrego un nuevo elemento a la lista no lo guarda en memoria?

Tags: python-3.x

`numero [1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Deseo agregar al final el número `7` para ir en orden

```
numero + [7]
```

Cuando lo ejecuto muestra la lista del `1` al `7`, pero si lo vuelvo a ejecutar o a llamar ya solo sale hasta el `6` ¿Por qué?

Comment: Bienvenido Malwarking a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Si `numero` es una lista,  una de las formas de agregar un elemento es usar `+`, pero si no asignas el resultado `numero` seguirá siendo la lista original. Prueba con `numero = numero + [7]`.

Comment: Otra forma es `numero += [7]`, que es lo mismo que `numero.extend([7])`, pero para agregar un único dato es más directo y legible `numero.append(7)` (observa que en este caso no hay corchetes alrededor del 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya te han respondido por qué tu variable `numero` no resulta modificada, y cómo lograr que se modifique. Yo mismo he sugerido en los comentarios varias alternativas. Quería ampliar un poco esa información que no me cabía en el comentario, enfocándolo desde el punto de vista de la eficiencia (en velocidad y en uso de memoria).

Básicamente las alternativas son:

- `numero = numero + [7]`
- `numero += [7]`
- `numero.extend([7])`
- `numero.append(7)`

La primera usa el operador `+` para concatenar listas. La forma en que python lleva a cabo esa operación consiste en primero hacer una copia de la lista que había en `numero`, después añadirle los elementos de la segunda lista tras el `+` (en este caso tiene un solo elemento, el 7). Eso completa la ejecución de lo que hay a la derecha del igual. La variable `numero` aún no ha sido modificada porque el 7 se añade a la copia que se ha realizado. Finalmente la asignación hace que la variable `numero` deje de referirse a la vieja lista que no tenía el 7 y pase a referirse a la nueva lista que sí lo tiene. La vieja lista aún está en memoria por un breve lapso de tiempo, hasta que el *recolector de basura* de python la elimine (este recolector detecta cuando un dato ya no tiene variables que se refieran a él).

El resto de soluciones no hacen esa copia en memoria, sino que trabajan directamente sobre la lista original:

- `numero.append(7)` sirve para añadirle un dato a la lista referenciada por `numero`. No se crean listas temporales. `numero` será una referencia a la misma lista, pero esa lista tendrá un elemento más.
- `numero.extend([7])` sirve para añadirle más de un dato a la lista. Es similar a `append()`, pero el parámetro que le pasas, en lugar de ser un dato, es otra lista. Todos los datos de esta segunda lista se añaden a la original, sin hacer una copia intermedia.
- `numero += [7]`, aunque a primera vista pudiera parecer que es equivalente a `numero = numero + [7]`, en realidad no lo es, porque Python convierte el operador `+=` en la operación `.extend()`, por tanto esta sintaxis nos lleva al caso anterior.

¿Qué importancia tiene si se crea una copia auxiliar temporalmente? Pues no mucha, pues la lista original enseguida desaparece, pero si vas a añadir muchos elementos a una lista en un bucle, cada iteración del bucle supondría la copia de la lista original, el añadido de un dato a la copia, y la destrucción de la lista original. A la larga eso se nota a medida que el bucle itera muchas veces. Por eso se recomienda usar en cambio `.append()`.

### Bonus

Casi lo mismo cabe decir para las cadenas, pero con un matiz importante: las cadenas son **inmutables**, lo que agrava el problema.

Si quieres añadir una letra a una cadena la solución intuitiva sería:

```
cadena = cadena + letra
```

En este caso, de hecho, no hay otra opción ya que al ser los `strings` *inmutables*, no tienen el método `.append()`, ni el método `.extend()`. Esto implica también que `cadena += letra` no puede ser convertido por Python en `cadena.extend(letra)`, porque como he dicho ese método no existe en un string. Es convertido a `cadena = cadena + letra`.

La concatenación de cadenas implica lo mismo que en las listas, es decir,  la creación de una cadena auxiliar que sea igual a la original más la letra añadida, y la destrucción de la cadena original.

Si la operación de añadir letras ocurre dentro de un bucle, se incurrirá entonces en la misma penalización ya comentada en las listas. Si esto es un problema y quieres mayor velocidad, se recomienda seguir el siguiente *patrón*: Convierte la cadena original en lista; añade letras a la lista mediante `.append()`, y al final convierte la lista resultante de nuevo en cadena. Es decir:

```
cadena = "Numeros:"
lista = list(cadena)
for i in range(20):
   # Añadiremos a la lista cadenas numéricas
   lista.append(str(i))
# Convertimos la lista resultante de nuevo en cadena
cadena = "".join(lista)
```

Al final de este bucle la cadena será: `'Numeros:012345678910111213141516171819'`

Answer (score 0):

En python el operador + utilizado en listas funciona como concatenador, pero no modifica los operandos o argumentos.

```
numero = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  # crea una lista y lo asigna a la variable numero
numero + [7]  # concatena las listas numero y [7] pero no modifica los operandos
```

si quisieramos que modifique el valor de numero podriamos hacerlo asi

```
numero = numero + [7] # concatena las listas numero y [7] y el resultado lo asigna a la variable numero
```